# Best practice for moving fastlane deployment of whitelabel apps off local machine and to a server/service

Tags: ios, circleci, fastlane

We create iOS and Android apps that are white-labeled. They all use a single code base (one for iOS and one for Android). Whenever we need to make changes to all of our apps (> 100 live in App Store) we rely on Fastlane. We have a "bulk" command that submits each new build to Apple, changing out config variables first and a few files so each app is unique.

This has worked well for us... but... its getting really slow. We'd love to be able to take advantage of some of the continuous development services out there. It seems like they weren't necessarily made for this use case but it might still work?

Ideally instead of running bulk on a local machine we could spin up 100 instances on something like CircleCI and they all run side by side, using our fastlane script to build, submit, etc.

We started by looking into CircleCI. The problem we are running into is they don't allow injection of variables into a job (https://ideas.circleci.com/ideas/CCI-I-690).

Is there a better service for this goal? Is there a tool that was built to achieve this? Struggling to find an alternative to hacking together a bunch of smaller tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already identified your first step: You will have to split your fastlane (and other tooling) configuration, so it is possible to build each app in isolation.

Then you can trigger a job for each app on a CI service like for example Travis CI or Azure Pipelines (both have a simple API you can use to start jobs and give them some parameters that will be available to your job) that builds and releases the app.

All the other things (e.g. one big build vs. many small build steps etc.) are just implementation details and will depend on the individual service or tools you choose.